# Переклад слова "trolling"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Цікавить переклад англійського слова "[trolling](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trolling)", яке має значення "розміщення в Інтернеті провокаційних повідомлень з метою викликати  конфлікти між учасниками, образи, війну редагувань, марнослів'я тощо". Гугл перекладач дає варіант "[троллінг](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/trolling)", але от на сторінці [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3) та [ТСН](https://prosport.tsn.ua/sport/troling-riven-bog-u-centri-kiyeva-vstanovili-baner-zi-skandalnim-foto-pavelka-z-kubkom-ligi-chempioniv-1160619.html) це слово пишеться з однією буквою "л" - "тролінг", то який із цих варіантів правильний?

Також цікаво чи є в українській мові хороший відповідник, яким би можна було замінити це слово. На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/trolinh) є такий цікавий варіант як злецювання, однак такого слова немає в СУМі. Особисто я вважаю, що його можна було б замінити словом "[штукарство](http://sum.in.ua/s/shtukarstvo)" або "онлайн штукарство", а слово "троль" ("troll") - "штукар". І все ж, я не впевнений, що це буде хороший переклад, тому можливо хтось може порадити кращі варіанти.

Comment: Можу лиш підкрипити вашу невпевненість: [Штука 2, и](http://sum.in.ua/s/shtuka), _жін., діал._ Мистецтво. Приклад вживу на новинарному осідку [Zbruč](//zbruc.eu/) — про всяк випадок [зображення](//cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/282525399198728203/449807502029357056/unknown.png "Штука — як один з розділів осідку"). Хоча деякі є [словники](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53416/276196.html "ШТУКАР 
д! ФІГЛЯР; П. жартівник, забавник, пустун.") і на вашу користь. Про всяк також зазначу, що [штука](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/штука#Etymology) — не питоме українське слово.

Answer (score 2):

***Тролінг*** з одним `-л-`, бо в загальних назвах іншомовного походження подвоєння зазвичай не зберігаються [Український правопис § 89](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm)

На мою думку, найбільш вдалим є варіант представлений на [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/trolinh) ***глузування***.

З СУМ-20

> ***[Глузування](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18791&page=643)*** я, с. Дія за знач. глузува́ти.
>
> ***[Глузувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18792&page=643)*** у́ю, у́єш, недок., з кого – чого і без дод., над ким – чим. Уїдливо насміхатися; висміювати когось або щось

Comment: А як у такому перекласти слово "troll" від якого походить "тролінг"?

Comment: @Анатолій так, дещо неуважно прочитала запитання.  "troll" можливо просто "троль" (http://sum.in.ua/s/trolj)